# Appending row to table javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to append a row to table. However, the row contents are complicated (it has inline listeners, plugins, href, etc). So, I would like to know what would be the best way to build this row. These are my options

1. Should I create a long string and set to row.innerHTML and call the
   plugins once the row is append to table
2. Should I create a separate .php file that creates the row and pass
   variables to set my values and then load the resulting html through
   ajax.
3. Should create element by element using `document.createElement()`
   and setting the values.

Or is there any other alternative that I should consider and provides a decent performance?

I forgot, what about cloning the row and changing the values?

Comment: Why inline listeners? What plugins? What does `href` matter?

Comment: have you consider using jquery?

Comment: All those methods will work. There's no objective criteria to define which is best, it's whatever you find most convenient and fits your application design.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the reply. Why inline listeners? I have done some reading and as far as I understood inline listeners may be a better choice for some scenarios. As for the plugins, I have a pickaday plugin to name one. Last, href matters because it takes you to a different page depending on the item contained in each row!

Comment: I know jQuery would make it really easy. However, all my code is in javascript and would not like the hulk of the library for just this part of the page. Thanks everyone for your replies. More than welcome to comment, if you have better ideas!

Comment: If every row has different listeners, maybe. If they all behave predictably, make a listener on a higher element and filter the events based on `event.target` classes or something; then you don't need to clutter each element with listeners. `href` being there is not really a consideration, given that it would be handled exactly the same in all three methods.